# PersonalInfo matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I wanted to add a multiple choice field to my form and after searching I finally made it work. however, when I create a new user and try to fill the personal info form, it gives me PersonalInfo matching query does not exist error. these are my codes:
models.py:

```
class Field(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='default')
    title = CharField(max_length=32)


class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    isCompleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    interested_fields = models.ManyToManyField(Field, blank=True)
```

forms.py:

```
class InterestedFieldsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    interested_fields = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset=Field.objects.all(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = PersonalInfo
        fields = ['interested_fields']
```

views.py:

```
class PersonalView(View):
    template_name = 'reg/personal.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        context['fields'] = Field.objects.all()
        return render(request, self.template_name, context=context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = InterestedFieldsForm(request.POST, instance=PersonalInfo.objects.get(user=user))
            if form.is_valid():
                profile = form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = request.user
                profile.save()
                form.save_m2m()
        else:
            form = InterestedFieldsForm()

        return render(request, 'reg/done.html', context={'form': form})
```

I know that the issue is because of this line in views:
form = InterestedFieldsForm(request.POST, instance=PersonalInfo.objects.get(user=user))
when I remove the instance, the form gets saved as the users' personal info but form wont replace the previous, it creates a new one. then again I put instance back and try to save the form and everything works just fine. what is causing this problem?

Comment: Your user has no related `PersonalInfo` record.

Comment: I know, I want to create one for it using this form. what should I do exactly

Comment: Use `get_or_create` to create one if it doesn't exist - `instance=PersonalInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user)[0]`

Comment: where and how? could you elaborate more? im new to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class PersonalInfo(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    isCompleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    interested_fields = models.ManyToManyField(Field, blank=True)
    ### add this
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='personal_info')
```

Do the migration process, then in your view:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        personalInfo, created = PersonalInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        form = InterestedFieldsForm(request.POST, instance=personalInfo)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile = form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = request.user
            profile.save()
            form.save_m2m()
    else:
        form = InterestedFieldsForm()

    return render(request, 'reg/done.html', context={'form': form})
```